# What is this antenna and what is its radiation pattern

Tags: antenna, pcb-antenna

Sometimes, there are interesting antennas in the market.
[image: antenna1]
As often, the seller knows few things or nothing about it.

This is what they say about it:

> Feature:
>
> 1. Antenna frequency 740-6000MHz, good reception signal.
> 2. Gain 6-7db, wide acceptance range, 50W power.
> 3. Made of high quality printed circuit board material, sturdy, durable and long service life.
> 4. Professional manufacturing, stable characteristics and high reliability.
> 5. Fine workmanship, simple designed, easy to install and operate, convenient to use.
>
> Specification: Condition: 100% Brand New Item Type: Antenna Material:
> Printed Circuit Board Color: As Pictures Shown Quantity: 1PCS Antenna
> Frequency: 740-6000MHz Antenna Standing Waves: Less Than 2(Typical
> Value) Antenna Polarization: Directional Line Polarization Antenna
> Gain: 6--7dB Power Capacity: 50W Connector Type: for SMA-K(Standard
> Female Head, External Screw Internal Hole) Weight: Approx. 71g Shape
> Size: Approx. 15×20cm/5.91x7.87inch

But no S11 or SVWR plot, no radiation pattern schematic.

Do you know what is the generic name of this antenna?
Do you know something about its radiation pattern.

Comment: Looks like it's a PCB version of an old fashioned long range VHF antenna, like the one on the opening page here: https://www.antennajunkies.com/best-long-range-outdoor-hdtv-antenna/.  Just a bunch of dipoles cut to different lengths for the frequency range of concern, 740 MHz to 6 GHz.

Comment: Have a look at **Log-periodic** widebandwidth antenna.

Comment: If the antenna manufacturer can't give proper specifications, why do you trust them to give you a proper antenna? If they measured these specifications, they would share them.

Comment: Hi @Joren. Well, it often appears the seller don't know how to sell electronic products he has bought from local manufacturers.